# ¿Que hacemos con preguntas que contienen enlaces a sitios NSFW?

Tags: discusión, ediciones

Esta pregunta viene motivada por esta otra y su posterior edición por @Mariano: [Duda usando Curl y file() en php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/137338/15301)

En este caso, obviamente el enlace no era relevante para la resolución de la pregunta, por lo que estoy totalmente de acuerdo en que era innecesario y en su eliminación.

Pero...¿que pasa si la URL sí es relevante para la comprensión y resolución del problema? Imaginemos que es un caso de web scrapping o api. ¿Debemos aún así eliminar el enlace? ¿Perdemos una posible buena pregunta/respuesta por un enlace NSFW*?

Aclaro que me refiero siempre a enlaces **dentro del snippet de código**, que sean relevantes y no un intento claro de publicidad o trolleo.

<sub>Por si alguien no conoce el significado, *NSFW* son las siglas de *Not safe for work*, se aplica a páginas con contenido pornográfico o incluso ilegal</sub>

Comment: Agrego que tuvimos varios comentarios en la pregunta (que luego eliminamos), no sobre la pregunta en sí, sino sobre este caso hipotético, y nos pareció mejor preguntar acá.

Comment: Así es,@Mariano y yo pensamos que era mejor una pregunta aquí que discutirlo en unos comentarios. Y efectivamente, la pregunta trata sobre un caso hipotético, la pregunta que motivó esta publicación está fuera de discusión ya que el enlace era totalmente irrelevante.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo lo he comentado en la sala de chat de moderadores de la red StackExchange.

La opinión de quienes me contestaron parece ser que mientras no haya un contenido directo como fotos o videos en la publicación, y si el enlace no es spam si no parte del código, entonces no es tan horrible que esté el enlace ahí.

Sin embargo, prefieren que se cambie, por ejemplo *"site.com"*, en los casos que la URL no sea necesaria para resolver el problema.

Por mi parte lo mismo. Un enlace a un sitio así es un sitio al fin y al cabo, y **lo importante** sería poner un mensaje de advertencia sobre el contenido al que se accede con dicho enlace.

Comment: Si, por supuesto. En todo caso sería imprescindible poner una advertencia para que nadie copie y pegue el código para probarlo y se lleve una sorpresa desagradable (o agradable, según se mire)

Comment: Creo que es la misma opinión que tuvimos en los comentarios... Pero también, a mí me es muy difícil pensar en un caso en el que no se pueda generar un mcve sin ese enlace. Si es realmente necesario, perfecto, pero sería un caso muy raro... Al fin y al cabo, la idea es que todas las publicaciones vivan sin la necesidad de un link (que podría quedar obsoleto).

Comment: @Mariano en el caso de api's el enlace es fundamental. Y posiblemente muchas preguntas queden inservibles cuando esa api desaparezca pero aun podría ser válida la pregunta en cuanto al funcionamiento de extracción de datos o búsqueda.

Comment: @lois6b buen punto, y estoy de acuerdo... Es sólo que creo que buscar que la pregunta tenga el mayor grado de abstracción posible la hace una mejor pregunta, y se debería intentar editar para que sea así. Por ejemplo, mostrando la respuesta en crudo de esa API, sin necesidad de que quien quiera responder tenga que consumirla... Pero ya me estoy yendo por las ramas, la pregunta es sobre links *NSFW*, y creo que lo respondiste perfecto.

Answer (score -1):

[Centro de ayuda:](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

> No os animamos a hacer ediciones minúsculas o triviales: intenta
>   mejorar la publicación considerablemente cuando la edites, corrigiendo
>   todos los problemas que encuentres.

La edición aquí mencionada es minúscula e irrelevante.

No hace más clara la pregunta, más fácil de entender o de responder.
Tampoco elimina ruido, cosa que sí hace la siguiente edición quitando saludos.

Es en definitiva una edición que no contribuye en nada a resolver la duda sobre `file()` en Curl.
De hecho la empeora puesto que altera los datos de entrada. Unir los `$id` con la dirección original de pornhub te lleva a páginas que sí existen. Unir los `$id` con la nueva dirección da direcciones que no existen.

Desde un punto de vista técnico es una edición a revertir.
Hablando más en general, un enlace debiera eliminarse solo si :

- El contenido enlazado es ilegal. (En realidad no hace falta poner esta línea puesto que es un subconjunto de la siguiente).
- Poner el enlace está en contra de las normas de SO.

No es el caso del enlace de pornhub. Imagino entonces que se edita por una cuestión moralista. Camino muy espinos a recorrer, se sabe donde se empieza pero no donde se acaba. Si en vez de pornhub fuese uno de los siguintes, ¿lo habrías eliminado?

- Tweet de Trump discriminando a los negros e hispanos.
- Página de coprofilia.
- Videojuegos violentos, como el Call of Duty por ejemplo.
- Blog con críticas negativas a Stack Overflow.

Este es un sitio en que se respeta la libertad de  opinión, incluso las [opiniones más críticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1666/nuestro-gestor-de-comunidad-funciona?s=1%7C56.4667), no perdamos esto. Si no defiendo la libertad de expresión con las cosas que no me gustan cuando le llegue el turno a las que sí me gustan será demasiado tarde.

Comment: Estás asumiendo, erróneamente, que no me gusta el contenido de pornhub. Lo que me cuesta mucho entender en tu planteo es que no se está discerniendo entre una opinión y un fragmento de código con un enlace en un string.